# Excel: Retrieving text within range. Based on second range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I have a range of cells that I want to determine if they contain one of several strings.
The series of strings are stored in a second cell range.

To determine if the strings are in the ranged cells or not, I have found the answer several places: 
(Example: https://exceljet.net/formula/cell-contains-one-of-many-things)

What I would like to do in addition to the above link is have the forumla return the found string-value, presumably using Mid. The strings-values in this case will always be 5 characters in length.

Comment: Do you want a separate output for **each cell** in the first range or one output for **all the cells** in the first range??

Comment: If a cell in the first range contains several strings from the second range, do you want to all **all** of them??

Comment: Each cell in the first Range (the Searching Range) will require it's own returned value. The cells should ideally never contain more than one matching value, so finding the first match would be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this small user defined function:

```
Public Function CaptureSubStrings(r1 As Range, r2 As Range) As String
    Dim s As String, r As Range

    s = r1(1).Text
    For Each r In r2
        If InStr(1, s, r.Value) > 0 Then CaptureSubStrings = CaptureSubStrings & "," & r.Value
    Next r

    CaptureSubStrings = Mid(CaptureSubStrings, 2)
End Function
```

For example:

[image]

If more than one substring is found, a concatenated sub list is returned.

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

```
=CaptureSubString(A1,E$1:E$3)
```

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Yes, this does work. But I should have clarified that I would need it done in formulas only, which is why I omitted VBA from the tags. Have an 'answered' anyway because you did solve it under the provided criteria.